# Printing to Postcript from Vim with utf-8 encoding

Tags: vim

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2551507/printing-to-postscript-from-vim), that Unicode symbols printing as upside down question mark is most likely a Postcript problem.

Not being able to print from Vim is very annoying. My question is, can this be solved with a vim script? I need these Turkish characters print correctly: `ğ, ü, ö, ç ı`

There is no problem with screen encoding, all Turkish characters look good.

And sending to `TOhtml` does not work for me because of CSS. Dark background and light text does not print well on b&w laser printer.

I have these relevant lines in my `.vimrc` file:

```
scriptencoding utf-8
set guifont=Courier:h18
printfont=utf-8
encoding=utf-8
filencoding=utf-8
```

Answer (score 1):

I have never used Vim's `:hardcopy` and I honestly have no idea what need it serves, but that extract from your `vimrc` is wrong.

`:help 'printfont'`, `:help 'encoding'`, and `:help 'fileencoding'` are options and options are defined with the `:help :set` command:

```
set printfont=utf-8
set encoding=utf-8
set filencoding=utf-8
```

Without `set`, those lines would throw an error so I suspect that what you provided is not *exactly* what you have in your `vimrc`, which makes the exercise more difficult than it should.

Anyway…

- `printfont` expects a font name, like `courier`. Unless you actually have a font on your system called `utf-8`, that value is wrong and the most likely cause of your issue.
- `fileencoding` is buffer-local so having it in your `vimrc` is pointless. Also, its default value when not set is the value of `encoding` so defining that option to the same value as `encoding` makes it doubly pointless.

Comment: I fixed those in `.vimrc` nothing changed. It just uses default values. I'm using `MacVim` I wonder if that's the problem.

Comment: And in the help file for `printfont` I read this "{only available when compiled with the |+printer| feature}". I can find no information about `+printer`.

Comment: Vim can be built with or without specific feature. You can see which feature your particular Vim was built with with `:version`. FWIW, MacVim has `+printer`. Congratulations, you made me print from Vim for the first time: https://i.imgur.com/PtvA43l.png.

Comment: See `:help postscript-printing` for a description of the issue and `:help postscript-print-encoding` for possible solutions.

Comment: Thanks. Good to know. It looks like there is no solution. There is nothing wrong with my Courier font because all Turkish characters show without problem on the screen. And I don't think it makes sense to create a new "vector" by reading the Postscript manual. I can open the file in emacs and print from there.